# Spark UDAF with Window function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, user-defined-aggregate

In order to achieve my requirement *"Process the provided data using the provided external library"*, I had written an UDAF using spark-scala which was working fine until I get a scenario as below:

**TestWindowFunc.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestWindowFunc {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("TestWindowFunc")
      .master("local[3]")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "5g")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.udf.register("custAvg", new CustAvg)

    val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("header", "true")
      .csv("./src/main/resources/students_mark.csv")

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("testWindowFunc")

    val df1 = spark.sql("select X.*" +
      ", custAvg(ACT_MARK, OUT_OF) over (partition by STUDENT_ID order by ACT_MARK) a" +
      ", custAvg(ACT_MARK, OUT_OF) over (partition by STUDENT_ID order by ACT_MARK) b" +
      " from testWindowFunc X")

    df1.show()
  }
}
```

**CustAvg.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, IntegerType, LongType, StructField, StructType}

class CustAvg extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  var initializeCounter = 0
  var updateCounter = 0

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(
    StructField("act_mark", IntegerType),
    StructField("out_of", IntegerType)
  )
  )

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(
    StructField("act_mark_tot", LongType),
    StructField("out_of_tot", LongType)
  ))

  override def dataType: DataType = LongType

  override def deterministic: Boolean = false

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    initializeCounter += 1
    println("initialize:::" + initializeCounter)
    updateCounter = 0

    /**
     * initializing the external library for each window
     */
    //    uncomment the below lines to execute the function
    //    buffer(0) = 0L
    //    buffer(1) = 0L
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    updateCounter += 1
    println("update:::" + updateCounter)

    /**
     * sending data to the external library for each row of the respective window
     */
    //    uncomment the below lines to execute the function
    //    buffer(0) = buffer.getLong(0) + input.getInt(0)
    //    buffer(1) = buffer.getLong(1) + input.getInt(1)
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    throw new Exception("Merge Not Allowed")
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    println("evaluate:::" + updateCounter)

    /**
     * calling the external library to process the data
     */
    //    uncomment the below line to execute the function
    //    buffer.getLong(0)
  }
}
```

**students_mark.csv**

```
STUDENT_ID|ACT_MARK|OUT_OF
1|70|100
1|68|100
1|90|100
```

**Expected output**

```
initialize:::1
update:::1
evaluate:::1
update:::2
evaluate:::2
update:::3
evaluate:::3
initialize:::2
update:::1
evaluate:::1
update:::2
evaluate:::2
update:::3
evaluate:::3
```

**Actual output**

```
initialize:::1
initialize:::2
update:::1
update:::2
evaluate:::2
evaluate:::2
update:::3
update:::4
evaluate:::4
evaluate:::4
update:::5
update:::6
evaluate:::6
evaluate:::6
```

Is this how spark behaves for this scenario or I am doing anything wrong here?

Could someone please help me on this with most appropriate explanation.

**Version details:**

- scala: 2.11
- spark: 2.4.0

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The UDAF seems overkill to me, especially using vars. See if you can do what you're trying to do with base functions. sum(ACT_MARK) / sum(OUT_OF) over (partition by STUDENT_ID order by ACT_MARK). I also noticed you're not specifying the bounds of your window. Look up "rowsBetween" or "rangeBetween". Current Row vs Unbounded preceding, etc. Good luck.

Comment: @MouritsdeBeer My requirement can't be achieved with base functions, that's why I had written UDAF. Adding bounds also doesn't match the expected output. Also I had added the vars, just to show the visual difference, but that is not part of my actual code.

Comment: Try to reduce to one partition(coalesce(1)) the dataframe and execute only with one core. Do not trust the println in a muti-thread and multi-partition scenario.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 the actual data size is around 1.5 TB and doing coalesce(1) might run out of memory. And I was not trusting the println, I used it for just show off.

Comment: I see. UDAFs are hard. Don´t use vars inside, use the internal buffer.

Comment: I see. UDAFs are hard. Don´t use vars inside, use the internal buffer. It requires a long explanation. I think that the workflow goes more or less like: initialize is called once per particion, update is to update the internal buffer with one specific Row, merge is to merge the different buffers created for different partitions and evaluate is to apply a final reduce function to resulting buffer. It is hard to try to track every step in a Window of N partitions and cores. I try to include some example of some POC I did in the past